# Getting last record value only

Tags: php

I am getting only the last element value, like in my case i am trying to get value of $dwnld_name

but don't know where i am missing, so only getting download name for the last record

```
 <?php 
     global $cat_id;
     $dwnld_sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_dm_downloads";
     $dwnld_qry = mysql_query($dwnld_sql);
       while($dwnld_row = mysql_fetch_array($dwnld_qry)){
          echo $link = $dwnld_row['link'];
          echo $dwnld_name = $dwnld_row['name'];
        $cat_id = $dwnld_row['category'];
      }
    ?>        

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_dm_category";
        $myquery = mysql_query($sql);
          echo '<ul>';
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery)){
                   $x = $row['name'];
                   echo $x_id = $row['id'];
      ?>
             <li><a href="#"><?php echo $x; ?>
           <?php if($x_id == $cat_id) { ?>
              <ul>
             <li><?php echo $dwnld_name; ?></li>
              </ul>
         <?php } ?>
           </a></li>
           <?php echo "<br/>";
                 }
             echo '</ul>';
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because, you are taking the values from loop in strings.

Everytime loop runs, it overwrites the values by recent values.

You can create an array and append values to that and loop through that array using `foreach`

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php 
global $cat_id;
$dwnld_sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_dm_downloads";
$dwnld_qry = mysql_query($dwnld_sql);
$downloads = array();
 while($dwnld_row = mysql_fetch_array($dwnld_qry)){
        $downloads['link'] = $dwnld_row['link'];
        $downloads['dwnld_name'] = $dwnld_row['name'];
    $downloads['cat_id'] = $dwnld_row['category'];
}
?>
```

Now, loop through `$downloads` array.

**Note: Do not use mysql_ functions are they are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP.**

Comment: don't encourage use of `mysql_*` api, its deprecated, wordpres has  `$wpdb` use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo `$dwnld_name` in the loop, or save names into array.

With this solution you overwrite `$dwnld_name` variable in each loop and as a result after the loop you have the last record.